# How to get value from nested class attribute

Tags: c++

I have two classes Probe and Bactery. Inside the Probe class I have Bactery class instance. I'm wondering how to get the bactery number via probe object. For that I've created setter and getter. Like this:

```
class Bactery {
private:
     int number;
public:
    void setNumber(int number) {
        number = number;
        cout << number << endl;
    }
    int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
};

class Probe {
public:
    Bactery bactery;
};

int main()
{
    Probe probe;
    probe.bactery.setNumber(55);
    int x = probe.bactery.getNumber();
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The printed **x** value is some random number and not 55. What I should do to get the proper value of **bactery number**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good practice is to avoid using the same name for everything, e.g. `number = number;`. Which `number` is at left and at right?

Try disambiguation at least:

```
this->number = number;
```

Comment: Yes, this was the reason of problem. Thank you.

Comment: That's true. You probably shadow a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises in your **setNumber** function: when you write "*number*", it refers to the latest "*number*" variable the compiler knows about. In this case, it's not the class member as you expected but the argument.

Change your function like this:

```
void setNumber(int n) {
    number = n;
    cout << number << endl;
}
```